# react-virtualized InfiniteLoader Table not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a component ('Events') that shows events in a Table within an InfiniteLoader.  The loadMoreRows function loads data from a service endpoint.   Pretty straightforward stuff.   The issue is that the Table doesn't update with rows loaded with loadMoreRows.  The table only shows the hardcoded record that `list` is defined with.  I can see that loadMoreRows is getting called and that `list` is getting updated.  FWIW, this component it loaded within a Material-UI dashboard.

I feel like I'm missing something simple... But, I've been beating on this for a long time and I figure I should just ask for some help.

Here's the component

```
const list = [
  {
    event: '123123-5eb4-498f-9d3a-123123123123',
    url: 'blahblha',
    category: 'Amazing Widgets',
  },
];

const remoteRowCount = 1000;

export default class Event extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    const sortDirection = SortDirection.ASC;
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {
      sortDirection,
    };
  }

  isRowLoaded({index}) {
    return !!list[index];
  }

  loadMoreRows({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
    console.log('finding', startIndex, stopIndex);
    return eventService.find().then(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        list.push({
          event: data[i].event_id,
          url: data[i].page_url,
          category: data[i].se_category,
        });
      }
      console.log(list);
    });
  }

  // Render your list
  render() {
    return (
      <InfiniteLoader
        isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded}
        loadMoreRows={this.loadMoreRows}
        rowCount={remoteRowCount}
      >
        {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
          <Table
            ref={registerChild}
            onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
            headerHeight={40}
            width={300}
            height={300}
            rowHeight={40}
            rowCount={list.length}
            rowGetter={({index}) => list[index]}
          >
            <Column label="Event" dataKey="event" width={300}/>
            <Column label="Url" dataKey="url" width={400}/>
            <Column label="Category" dataKey="category" width={100}/>
          </Table>
        )}
      </InfiniteLoader>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the first 6  elements in list after loadMoreRows is finished.

```
0: {event: "123123-5eb4-498f-9d3a-123123123123", url: "blahblha", category: "Amazing Widgets"}
1: {event: "dbcbb9af-2ab0-47c1-8acc-94ee1aef451d", url: "blahblha", category: "Bing Bong"}
2: {event: "bd134bbf-a227-4fb4-b3ea-28ae0e267a10", url: "blahblha", category: "Bing Bong"}
3: {event: "9aefce0c-fcbe-4e9e-b20c-28fcff7c6f14", url: "blahblha", category: "Bing Bong"}
4: {event: "32d13a5f-c2d8-448d-9bdf-5f23f95ff12b", url: "blahblha", category: "Bing Bong"}
5: {event: "e0e7d374-5d97-4d63-836e-d31ca302143f", url: "blahblha", category: "Bing Bong"}
6: {event: "88e60b53-3f8e-4e1d-bbd7-ef3fea0ade1d", url: "blahblha", category: "Bing Bong"}
```

like I said, I only see element 0.

There are no errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per [InfiniteLoader in GitHub](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md), your loadMoreRows function should return a Promise:  "The returned Promise should be resolved once row data has finished loading. It will be used to determine when to refresh the list with the newly-loaded data. This callback may be called multiple times in reaction to a single scroll event."

for example:

```
function loadMoreRows({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        eventService.find().then(data => {
            ...
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```